# Get textbox id from dynamic table in td

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have a dynamic table like below, I need validate every textbox. I am able to do only first text box. I can't do remaining.

[image: Table]

My Code:

```
foreach{ // for reference

          <%: Html.TextBox("Qty", "", new { Id = "Qty_Id"})%>

}



    $(function () {
        debugger;
        $('#Qty_Id').blur(function () {
            var QtyVal = $('#Qty_Id').val();
            var $regexmatch = /^[0-9]*$/;

            if (!$.isNumeric(QtyVal) || !QtyVal.match($regexmatch)) {
                IsValid = false;
                alert("Quantity must be number..!");
                $('#Qty_Id').val('');
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: You can only have a maximum of one element with any given id value per page.

Answer (score 1):

### The problem

You can only have a maximum of one element with any given `id` value per page.

As of now, you are creating multiple elements with the same `id`. This makes your HTML invalid. If you have duplicate `id` values in the page, Javascript (and also jQuery) will always **only return the first element with that given id**. That is the reason it works only for the first dropdown in your code.

### A Solution

Instead of `id` use `class`:

```
foreach{ // for reference
      <%: Html.TextBox("Qty", "", new { Class = "Qty_Class"})%>
}



$(function () {
    debugger;
    $('.Qty_Id').blur(function () {
        var QtyVal = $(this).val();
        var $regexmatch = /^[0-9]*$/;

        if (!$.isNumeric(QtyVal) || !QtyVal.match($regexmatch)) {
            IsValid = false;
            alert("Quantity must be number..!");
            $(this).val('');
        }
    });
});
```

Also, inside your event handler you have access to the element that caused the event using `this`.